# VB ASP.NET. "the conversion overflowed an integer column."

Tags: sql, vb.net, int

I am working in VB ASP.NET.  I am doing a SELECT.  I have a variable in the WHERE clause that usually works, but when I enter 13 or more characters, I get the message "the conversionnvarchar value overflowed an integer column."  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT VACD
FROM VENDOR
WHERE VACD = FORM.VACD
```

Comment: What are the DataTypes of your columns??

Comment: Well, seeing as [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) only has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, I don't see how even a 12 digit number can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you mix characters and numbers in a comparison you might get an implicit conversion.  I might be wrong since as @Oded said: even 12 digits shouldn't be usable.  [Better explanation.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/b6726828-d6c2-4bb8-b7ad-2de57efd31bf)

Answer (score 0):

Character values are implicitly converted to integers when they are compared to. So this means that your 13 characters will be to large for the Int32 number which ranges from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.